# ASP.Net MVC Ajax.Beginform giving unexpected results when clicking quickly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, ajax.beginform

I am using ASP.Net MVC ajax.beginform to change the content in a panel, I am also switching some other elements on the page with javascript,

if I click quickly between two of the options the javascript behaves as expected but the ajax does not always return the content related to the last clicked button.

anyone else had this problem and are there any fixes or workarounds?

Cheers.

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal, AJAX is asynchronous meaning that the order you would receive responses from the server is not guaranteed to be the same as you send the requests. You might need to queue the requests. There are some good [jquery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) that allow you to [achieve this](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=173). But with MS Ajax I doubt.